# Array interpolation, But padding with only source values - without insert new values - Python

Tags: python, interpolation

I have a python array (old_array) in size N (N=1920) and I want to interpolate it to a new array (new_array) in size M (M=2823)

Usually, I use interpolation on an old array like this:

```
from scipy.interpolate import make_interp_spline
Spline_object = make_interp_spline(x_axis, old_array) # len(x_axis) == len(old_array)
N=1920
M=2823
X = np.linspace(x_axis.min(), x_axis.max(), M)
new_array = Spline_object(X)
```

But in this way, I get a new array of values between source values. But I need to pad the space only with source values and not insert new values.

For example, if N=1000, M=2000 so: `new_array[0:2] = old_array[0], new_array[2:4] = old_array[1]`  etc.

This is simple and easy to do.
But I'm trying to find a way to do it in nonlinear cases. (2823/1920 = 0.6801275239107333)

Thanks

Comment: `2823/1920 = 0.6801275239107333`?

Comment: What I try to say is that if the ratio is like 2:1 - 0.5 I can do it easily but when the ratio is more ugly like 0.6 I have no idea how to do it/

Comment: Yes, I got it, it's just that `2823/1920≈1.47` :P Besides, your question can be rephrased as "how to approximate a line with a given slope", and, searching for this you can find [many more results](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_drawing_algorithm).

Comment: There is a difference between what you suggest to what I need. I cant APPROXIMATE i need to use only the values from the source array. 
if we draw the line after it , looks like a stairs graph

Comment: Maybe it was unclear, as I did not really explain: in horizontal, you have indexes of `old_array`, in vertical the indexes of `new_array`. You draw a line from `(0, 0)` to `(1920, 2823)`, and each point you "draw" (even if you wouldn't actually draw anything) according to the line-drawing algorithm means you at coordinate `(x, y)` means that `new_array[y] = old_array[x]`. This way you are padding in the "best" way possible.